# Write a photo taken from camera using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to external storage on Android 11

Tags: android, android-camera, android-11, android-image-capture

I'm trying to take a photo using `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` and save it to the external cache. Before starting the Activity I ask for `CAMERA`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.
The code example of the `Intent` creation below:

```
private Intent createIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri resultUri = null;
    File path = context.getExternalCacheDir();
    if (path != null && !path.exists() && !path.mkdirs()){
          return null;
    }
    File file = new File(path.getPath(), "resultImage.jpeg");
    if (path != null) {
       resultUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
       context,
       context.getPackageName() + ".provider",
       file);
    }
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, resultUri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    return intent;
}
```

On devices running with Android 10 and lower it works fine but on Android 11 I'm getting this error and receive `RESULT_CANCELED` or just crash in the Camera app.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.GoogleCamera, PID: 19689
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GCA not granted write permission to content://com.example.debug.provider/external_cache/resultImage.jpeg, the specified output in intent: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x2 cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity (has extras) }.
        at mtt.run(PG:1)
        at bph.run(Unknown Source:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GCA not granted write permission to content://com.example.debug.provider/external_cache/resultImage.jpeg, the specified output in intent: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x2 cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity (has extras) }.
```

My File Provider:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

and provider path's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/"/>
    <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

I also tried to use `getExternalFilesDir` instead of cache but got the same error.

Comment: `createIntent()` returns an `Intent`. Can you show the code where you make that call and use the result for `startActivityForResult()`? In particular, I am wondering if perhaps you are calling `setFlags()` on the `Intent`, as that would wipe out the `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` flag that you add in `createIntent()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi! I have a wrapper class to start an Activity for result, so I can't show you the exact code. But I just check and there're no calls of `setFlags()` fun only  `addFlags()`. My app's targetSdk is 29 and I also tried to use `requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` flag in Manifest but it didn't work as well.